# Turn string into date - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am retrieving a value from an input box and am using that value to turn into a `Date` for `JavaScript`  the format is `Y-m-d h:i:s`.  It works perfect in Chrome but any other browser says `invalid Date`

```
var old = $(".checked-in-time").val();
old = new Date(old);
```

UPDATE:

Here is what I am doing:

```
var current = new Date();
var old = $(".checked-in-time").val();
old = Date.parse(old , 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
var newEnd = current - old
minutes = parseInt((newEnd/(1000*60))%60);
var subtractedWaitTime = minutes;
```

Pretty much getting the time difference based on minutes.

Comment: `Y-m-dTH:i:s` is it a valid format?

Comment: ops sorry check update

Comment: `Date.parse("dateString")` takes only one string parameter and returns time in milliseconds.

Comment: Yes I know which is why I was using `new Date(old);`  but using moment was the solution i took.  It works great now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.parse accepts a limited number of formats:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Your format is not one of the ones supported.  You can parse it yourself and just pass the arguments directly. One of the forms Date accepts is this, which would be easy enough to pull out from your format:

```
new Date(year, month[, date[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

But I would recommend removing the pain of having to worry about cross browser compatibility and parsing things yourself, and use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) instead, where you can parse the date like this

```
moment(dateStr,'YYYY-M-D H:m:s')
```

and then if you needed to have it as a Javascript Date object you could just run

```
moment().toDate();
```

in the more likely case you just need to display it formatted somewhere, or compare it to other dates, moment offers many functions for formatting, manipulating and comparing dates

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/

Answer (score 1):

You can parse date like this,

```
var old = $(".checked-in-time").val();
old = Date.parseDate(old , 'yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s');
```

if the above not working, you can also try `Y-m-d H:i:s` this format. For me `Y/m/d H:i` worked fine.

Comment: Keeps telling me invalid date.  Here is what my input box looks like `2015-01-19 22:29:41`

Comment: also Date.parseDate is not defined as a function for me?

Comment: Which jQuery version you are using?

Comment: `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: if I just do `Date.parse` it keeps telling me `NaN`

Comment: do you mean the format of my input or the `parse` format section?

Comment: do you want your date in milliseconds? or just format it in your type?

Comment: this won't work, `Date.parseDate` doesn't exist, and `Date.parse` only accepts a single argument. `moment` works like this, but `Date` does not.   Also Date is not a jQuery function, so his jQuery version should be irrelevant.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following formats

- MM-dd-yyyy
- yyyy/MM/dd
- MM/dd/yyyy
- MMMM dd, yyyy
- MMM dd, yyyy

Could be that some browsers don't support yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @David Biga it would be .parse() not .parseDate() like VPK suggested

Answer (score 1):

You could try use such format `Y-m-dTH:i:s`, e.g. `2011-01-01T12:00:00`

Or you can use [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library (Javascript Date library)